# Error while running Qt application with wayland

Tags: 18.04, application-development, qt, wayland, qt5

I am trying to run a simple Qt application Hello World on Ubuntu 18.04 desktop with Wayland. Following commands, I tried.

```
$ export QT_QPA_PLATFORM=wayland
$ ./qello
also tried with following command
$ ./qello -platform wayland
```

but I am getting the same error.

```
$ ./qello -platform wayland
Failed to create wl_display (No such file or directory)
qt.qpa.plugin: Could not load the Qt platform plugin "wayland" in "" even though it was found.
This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.

Available platform plugins are: eglfs, linuxfb, minimal, minimalegl, offscreen, vnc, wayland-egl, wayland, wayland-xcomposite-egl, wayland-xcomposite-glx, webgl, xcb.
Aborted (core dumped)
```

I have installed `weston-launch`. I am able to run that in virtual terminal <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>.
Do I need to install any package or need to do some configuration?